# Перенос коммитов в другую ветку

Tags: git, git-branch

На проекте есть ветки: `master`, `dev`, `branch1`, `branch2`, ... Я создал новую ветку, но потом опять перешел на ветку `dev` и, так получилось, забыл про это и продолжил писать код в ветке `dev`.

**Вопрос:** можно ли перенести изменения, которые я сделал в ветке `dev`, в другую ветку? При этом, чтобы в ветке `dev` они пропали.

Comment: "Изменения, которые я сделал в ветке `dev`" - вы их коммитили? Потому что иначе они пока ни в какой не в ветке.

Comment: @vp_arth нет, изменения я не коммитил

Answer (score 3):

```
git add .

git stash
```

Переходите в другугую ветку

```
git stash apply
```

Comment: Не apply, а pop. Или эти изменения так и останутся мусором в стеше. Ну и автор не говорил, что ничего не коммитил..

Comment: Ну если бы закомиттил тогда `git cherry-pick`

Answer (score 2):

Если вы уже сделали ветку `branch3` и сделали коммиты в `dev`, то тогда:

```
git checkout branch3
git merge dev
git checkout dev
git reset --hard HEAD~3 
git checkout branch3
```

В данном случае вы откатываете 3 коммита (`HEAD~3`) назад в ветке `dev`. Сколько вам надо откатить - смотрите по истории.